# MultipartFormDataStreamProvider vs HttpContext.Current

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I am struggling to understand why would I want to use MultipartFormDataStreamProvider when I can get all the information using HttpContext.Current.

It is much easier to do this:

```
var mydata = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["mydata"];
```

than this:

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/somedir");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

this.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    var mydata = provider.Contents.First(c => c.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"mydata\"").ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
});
```

PS - I am trying to build an ApiController to accept file uploads. I've read this article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2.

Comment: One reason would be the ability to read content asynchronously.

Comment: Another reason is that this would not work in self hosted scenarios since you are dependent on `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: It seems unfortunate that this the use of this method when using WebAPI requires the file to be written to disk in the path specified. There is no official documentation indicating on what is written, why, or indicate that app is responsible for deleting the files after. A lot of overhead considering the file is already in stream.

Comment: HttpContext.Current is part of the monolithic System.Web, and it is going away in future versions of ASP.NET. Web API is designed to be forward-compatible with ASP.NET vNext.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` also doesn't work in unit-tests, where you would use OWIN's `TestServer`

Answer (score 4):

This is what I found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.multipartformdatastreamprovider%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). I think this might help you.

The stream provider looks at the **Content-Disposition** header field and determines an output Stream based on the presence of a **filename** parameter. If a **filename** parameter is present in the **Content-Disposition** header field then the body part is written to a FileStream, otherwise it is written to a MemoryStream. This makes it convenient to process MIME Multipart HTML Form data which is a combination of form data and file content.

Comment: Could you point to an example that posts both file and form data using HttpClient?