# Using ASP.NET WebAPI v2, how do I POST PDF data in a WebAPI method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, asp.net-web-api

The idea is that there will be an external entity (SharePoint) that will call my WebAPI and pass in a PDF file as well as some extra, metadata information about that PDF file.  I'm stuck on how to construct the signature of the Web API method.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public class IssueController : ApiController
{
    private TestEntities db = new TestEntities(HelperClasses.ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString());

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SavePdf(Article a)
    {
        // save the PDF to a file share & metadata to the SQL database
    }
}
```

My inclination would be to do something like:

```
public class IssueController : ApiController
{
    private TestEntities db = new TestEntities(HelperClasses.ConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString());

    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SavePdf(Article a, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // save the PDF to a file share & metadata to the SQL database
    }
}
```

But, I'm not sure with WebAPI how to exactly do this.

**QUESTION**: How would I define a WebAPI method capable of accepting PDF data & some extra metadata as a `POST` request from an external entity?

Comment: Have you seen the answering here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi

Comment: Okay, so a file is a file, treat them all the same?

Comment: that's the approach I would take. Makes your controller a little more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass complex object , i suggest you to use JObject.

JObject: http://blog.travisgosselin.com/web-api-signatures-with-multiple-complex-parameters/

PostFiles: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2