# What is the best way to pass an Excel file to a WEB API web service

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass an Excel file in to and web service implemented in C#. The web service I have created so far is as follows.

```
 public void loadData([FromBody]string dataFile)
        {

        }
```

I also thought that it is accepatble to pass the Excel file is using a Base64 string;
Is this a good way or are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: you could send it via RFC 1149-compliant links. doesn't really matter how you send it. what matters is what the webservice expects/requires.

Comment: so is accepting the file as string ok?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you pass the file as part of a multipart/form-data HTTP request.

[How To Accept a File POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi)

[Sending HTML Form Data in ASP.NET Web API: File Upload and Multipart MIME](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-2)

Edit:
To receive a binary file of any type, use the following code. However, this is fairly unsafe. Really, the request headers should be checked for content type and content length.

```
public void loadData() {
    /* get raw data */
    string dataFile = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
}
```

[Accepting Raw Request Body Content with ASP.NET Web API](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/13/Accepting-Raw-Request-Body-Content-with-ASPNET-Web-API)

Comment: will the web service still be the same? I am referring to the public void loadData([FromBody]string dataFile)

Comment: In my opinion, it's not a good idea to pass a file as a string. You don't have any idea what the type the file is, or what the actual binary length is. Also, mutlipart/form-data content type is the only way for HTML forms to submit files. Instead of mutlipart/form-data or base64 string, you can just send the file binary. http://blog.marcinbudny.com/2014/02/sending-binary-data-along-with-rest-api.html#.VH986zE73Fk

Comment: so what must be the signature of the method  public void loadData(?) if using  mutlipart/form-data content type

Comment: Edited the answer. It now includes links to do both ways.

Comment: I have the following check  if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }
But the string dataFile (Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result) is empty