# Save cropped image from ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I have been fooling around with a [ngImgCrop](http://jsfiddle.net/alexk111/rw6q9/) and [Accept a File POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi)

The image cropper uses ng-src to display an example of the cropped image:

```
ng-src="data:image/png;base64,...
```

I want to save that cropped image.
My problem is in the front-end, I have no idea where to and how to go from here.

Is there a way to save that cropped image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to upload a file: Convert the base64 string to a blob. A file using a file uploader is a blob with extra properties, so uploading a blob works the same.

```
var file = dataURItoBlob(dataURI, 'image/png');


function dataURItoBlob(dataURI, type) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
    var bb = new Blob([ab], { type: type });
    return bb;
}
```