# Simple image file POST to Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post, asp.net-web-api

I have been reading around building an action method in my Web Api to allow the posting of images, which would be saved on the server and related to a Contact object via a field `imageURL`.

I have found a few examples online of how to set this up, and am wanting to test them. I currently have:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile() 
{ 
    HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request; 
    if (!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) 
    { 
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType); 
    } 

    string root = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"); 
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root); 

    var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider). 
        ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o => 
    { 

        string file1 = provider.BodyPartFileNames.First().Value;
        //Use file name to update ImageURL of contact

        return new HttpResponseMessage() 
        { 
            Content = new StringContent("File uploaded.") 
        }; 
    } 
    ); 
    return task; 
}
```

from [How To Accept a File POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi), and whilst I understand the flow I want to test it properly.

**What would an example of a client call be to this API method, where I can include the contactid as a header?**

I need to understand this properly to test this code sample so I can start understanding this more, but I'm really new to this area. I have kind of a chicken and egg scenario where I understand little about posting and receiving images and need a start point.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are familiar with Java/Android, you can use Android Studio to create a client app that can upload file to Web API.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Java/Android unfortunately

Comment: I think there are some samples with Windows Phone app at http://asp.net/webpi

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small MVC or ASP application (you only need one page) where you can use some JS plugins to post files to your controller.
Plugins:  [jQueryFileUpload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) or [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). The last one is more easy to integrate. Both plugins has support for sending additional data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look! If they are drag 'n' drop, how would an API POST call to this page look?

Comment: See above. I didn't tag the comment

Comment: You can check the request payload using for DevTools (press F12) on Chrome an then Network tab. After that you press on the the request and You will see something similar with this [post](http://chxo.com/be2/20050724_93bf.html).

Comment: The `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` class will handle the file and will parse the additional  form data fields. After upload complete you can access `provider.FormData` and `provider.FileData` to get the serialized fields and access the file.