# How to implements upload web service in .NET

Tags: .net, web-services, file-upload, base64

I want to build a simple .NET web service to upload Image file.
I want use image with Base64, so for this, I have write this code but it is not correct.

```
[Route("SaveDocument")]
[WebMethod]
public bool SaveDocument(Byte[] docbinaryarray,string docname)
{
    string strdocPath;
    strdocPath = "C:\\DocumentDirectory\\" + docname;
    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    objfilestream.Write(docbinaryarray, 0, docbinaryarray.Length);
    objfilestream.Close();

    return true;
}
```

If I try to run my web service, it start, but if I try to use POSTMAN to call it, I receive error.

I call Web Service in this mode:

```
http://localhost:55649/SaveDocument
```

> The error is Eorr 500
>
> EDIT
>   I have change my code to this:

```
[Route("SaveDocument")]
[HttpPost]
public bool SaveDocument(Byte[] docbinaryarray, string docname)
{
    string strdocPath;
    strdocPath = "C:\\DocumentDirectory\\" + docname;
    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    objfilestream.Write(docbinaryarray, 0, docbinaryarray.Length);
    objfilestream.Close();

    return true;
}
```

> Now I can call the Web Service, to do this, I use PostMan, I insert this link:

```
http://localhost:55649/api/SaveDocument
```

In the body part I select Image file. So if I try to call this link, I have this error:

> ERROR
>   {
>     "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:55649/api/SaveDocument'.",
>     "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Omniacare' that matches the request."
>   }

Comment: Check your Application Event Log for error details. Most likely your IIS ApplicationPool user does not have privileges to write to C:\DocumentDirectory.

Comment: I have the privileges to write under C:\, and another point is, I have insert a break point at the first line of my method, and I'm not able to do debub because I receive error

Comment: Well what does the Application Event Log say? A server side 500 error of an asp.net webservice should show up there giving you a stacktrace containing more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Accept a File POST - ASP.Net MVC 4 WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi)