# How to read a javascript FormData object on .NET WebAPI 5.2.2

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, blob

I'm trying to implement a web cam video recording upload as per [this RecordRTC  example.](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/tree/master/RecordRTC-to-ASPNETMVC)

The problem is that "Request.Files" throws the following compiling error as shown in the screenshot.

`'HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'Files' and no extension method 'Files' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

[image]

What should I do in order to fix the error?

Comment: Check whether you have correct references, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be from the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` not from the `HttpRequestMessage`