# REST API sending images to requests

Tags: c#, rest

I have a function through which I am calling my REST API. I need to pass the image in the request. How do I achieve that?

for ex :

```
public int Save(Image image)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
}
```

here, how do I pass my 'image' to my request 'req'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like:

```
req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); //if it is jpeg
    string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    byte[] reqData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encoded);
    using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this on the client side:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var imageStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\p1.jpg");
var content = new StreamContent(imageStream);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
var response = await client.PostAsync("URL", content);
```

You can get **HttpClient** from the NugetPackage Microsoft.Net.Http

On the REST API side (receiving end), you can then take it from the Request.Content object, something like this:

```
public void Post()
{
            using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\NewFile.jpg"))
            {
                using (MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var task = this.Request.Content.CopyToAsync(tempStream);
                    task.Wait();

                    tempStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    tempStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                    tempStream.Close();
                }

            }
 }
```