# c# webrequest post image to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble uploading an image to a Web API that i'm running. I can retrieve data from the Web API when using GET requests, but I'm having trouble with POST requests. I need to upload an BMP image to the Web API and then send back a json string.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult TestByte()
{
    Log("TestByte function entered");
    //test to see if i get anything, not sure how to do this
    byte[] data = Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    byte[] test = Convert.FromBase64String(payload);

    if(test == null || test.Length <= 0)
    {
        Log("No Payload");
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (data == null || data.Length <= 0)
    {
        Log("No payload");
        return NotFound();
    }

    Log("Payload received");
    return Ok();

}
```

The MVC side that sends the image looks like this:

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";

// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
byte[] byteArray = GetImageData(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, content, barcodeUri));
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
byte[] dataArray = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(base64String);

// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;

// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close();

// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

For some reason I always get an 404 `WebException` on

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I have checked that the URL should be right. Is it how I format the URL for post or am I making some other mistake?

Edit, added webconfig routing:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post-asp-net-mvc-4-webapi)

Comment: You're setting the content as multipart/form-data but the stream isn't encoded as multipart, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 5):

You could use `multipart/form-data` to transmit the file. Here's an example of how you could read the contents of the uploaded file in your Web API action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return this.StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    var filesProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
    var fileContents = filesProvider.Contents.FirstOrDefault();
    if (fileContents == null)
    {
        return this.BadRequest("Missing file");
    }

    byte[] payload = await fileContents.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    // TODO: do something with the payload.
    // note that this method is reading the uploaded file in memory
    // which might not be optimal for large files. If you just want to
    // save the file to disk or stream it to another system over HTTP
    // you should work directly with the fileContents.ReadAsStreamAsync() stream

    return this.Ok(new
    {
        Result = "file uploaded successfully",
    });
}
```

and now writing a client is a trivial task using the [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static void Main()
    {
        string responsePayload = Upload().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine(responsePayload);
    }

    private static async Task<string> Upload()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:8180/api/upload");
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        byte[] byteArray = ... get your image payload from somewhere
        content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(byteArray), "file", "file.jpg");
        request.Content = content;

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting a 404 on `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();`. The URL I'm calling is `http://localhost:49289/api/upload`, I can see the localhost:49289 running in IIS express. I basically copied your code, no idea why I can't access the function in my web API.

Comment: Are you using attribute based routing on your Web API? In my example I did but this assumes that you have properly configured it. If you are using global routing then adapt the code to your scenario, don't just blindly copy-paste.

Comment: I have attribute based routing enabled in the Web API, I editted my original question to show my WebApiConfig

Comment: Try removing the global route from your config. You should not mix attribute with global routing.

Comment: I removed the global route and it's still not working. I still get a 404, but when I call the URL as a GET request from the browser I get `{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}`, it looks like it is there.

Comment: Hard to say why your code doesn't work. I have created a brand new Web API project, enabled attribute based routing and this code worked without issues for me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `string payload` parameter from the TestByte method. It causes error. You are getting the data by `Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync` method. You dont need payload object.
If your routing is correct it has to work like this.

Edit:
Can you change routeTemplate like this?

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
```

Comment: You are right about the payload parameter, I added it to test if it would change something, I removed it again. I'm using `Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync` but I think there is a problem with my routing. I'm not sure what to look for in my routing to resolve the issue. It should work, but when posting data I get a 404.