# API File Upload using HTTP content not exposed in swagger

Tags: c#, api, swagger

I am implementing a swagger interface into an existing web API. The current API controller exposes an async upload function which uses the `Request.Content` to transport an image asynchronously. The code that has been used is explained in [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-and-save-multipartform-data-in-webapi-2/) article.

My api controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("foo/bar/upload")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider());
        NameValueCollection formData = provider.FormData;
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        //access files  
        IList<HttpContent> files = provider.Files;
        if (files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpContent file1 = files[0];
            using (Stream input = await file1.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                object responseObj = ExternalProcessInputStream(input)
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseObj);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

This works dandy, but when i expose this through swagger i have a parameterless function, which returns an error when used.

My question is how can supply a proper value to test this method with?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to add a custom IOperationFilter to handle this.

Given you have a controller like so:

```
    [ValidateMimeMultipartContentFilter]
    [HttpPost, Route("softwarepackage")]
    public Task<SoftwarePackageModel> UploadSingleFile()
    {

        var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(ServerUploadFolder);
        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<SoftwarePackageModel>(t =>
        {
            var firstFile = streamProvider.FileData.FirstOrDefault();

            if (firstFile != null)
            {
                // Do something with firstFile.LocalFileName
            }

            return new SoftwarePackageModel
            {

            };
        });

        return task;
    }
```

You then need to create an Swashbuckle.Swagger.IOperationFilter to add a file upload parameter to your function like:

```
    public class FileOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            if (operation.operationId.ToLower() == "softwarepackage_uploadsinglefile")
            {
                if (operation.parameters == null)
                    operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>(1);
                else
                    operation.parameters.Clear();
                operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
                {
                    name = "File",
                    @in = "formData",
                    description = "Upload software package",
                    required = true,
                    type = "file"
                });
                operation.consumes.Add("application/form-data");
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your Swagger config you'll need to register the filter:

```
config.EnableSwagger(c => {... c.OperationFilter<FileOperationFilter>(); ... });
```

To top this up, I also added a FilterAttribute to filter out Multipart content:

```
public class ValidateMimeMultipartContentFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: This is a really good solution, and it works great for me. However, how do I set the contentType?

Comment: As an addendum to your answer, I found this, which does the same thing, except it adds an attribute that you can decorate your method with, as opposed to checking the operationID (which I found was annoying to figure out). http://tahirhassan.blogspot.co.il/2017/12/web-apiswagger-file-upload.html

Comment: For me this post was helpful too. Very similar: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-upload-file-via-swagger-in-asp-net-core-web-api/

Comment: Why did you use application/form-data as the mime type?  I would have expected multipart/form-data.