# upload entire model to API via AJAX (mvc c#)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working with Ajax, mvc and c#, uploading my model to my api action, using this information I found here: [stackoverflow: How to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681).

**This is my problem** When following step by step the above link, my model in the api side comes null:

```
//this is the conten of the viewmodel object in the api action
guid:{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
descripcion:null
Imagen:null
Title:null
```

This is my viewmodel

```
  public class myViewModel
{
    public Guid CursoId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(125)]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "select image file for course")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Imagen { get; set; } //note this is the image
}
```

My web api, it is a simple action to test

```
 // POST: api/Test
    [Route("test")]
    public void Post([FromBody]myViewModel model)
    {//do something
    }
```

this is my view:

```
 @model ajaxtest.ViewModel.myViewModel
<form id="Editcurso" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the following errors.")
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Titulo)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.Titulo, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Titulo)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.Descripcion)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(c => c.Descripcion, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descripcion)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Imagen)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Imagen, new { type = "file" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Imagen)
    </div>
    <button id="submiter" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Listo!</button>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
  $('#Editcurso').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit
            if (!$(this).valid()) {
                return; // exit the function and display the errors
            }


            jQuery.support.cors = true;
          // Create a formdata to pass the model, since the view was generated from viewmodel, it should contain the model.
            var model = new FormData($('#Editcurso').get(0));

            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                   'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                url: '/api/test/test',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return false;
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error al postear');
                    return false;
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        });

    });
```

What do you think is wrong and how can I fix it? thanks.

Comment: Start by removing `headers: { ... }` and its `data: model,` (not stringified)

Comment: if I remove the headers, I get this error: POST http://localhost:52922/api/test/test 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: You cannot use `Content-Type': 'application/json` is your uploading a file. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320232/how-to-accept-a-file-post) for an example (I'll see if I can find a better one shortly)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, I will  check it.  As another comment, I am still getting the unsupported media type