Trying to upload audio blob from angular to ASP.NET Web API
I am trying to upload an audio blob file from Angular, but I am not receiving any files on the server side. I tested my ASP.NET Web API code in ApiDog, and It's working without any issues. I need some suggestions about this issue.
My Angular code:
upload(blob: Blob): void {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file",blob,'audio file');
    
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});
    let options = { headers: headers };
    this.http.post('/api/fileUpload', formData,options).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
}

ASP.NET Web API:
I check the file count in the following code block on my controller.
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
{
    var file = httpRequest.Files[0];
}

Thanks for your time!

Do you see any errors on the developer console ? You should also read the comments on this answer when you are using HttpContext: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356591/1807452

I do not see any errors in the console tab. I will go through the comments you have provided. I think there is no issue with Web API because I can make successful rest calls from Postman / Api Dog and get the file in Api. I am having the issue only when doing a rest call from Angular.

Just to confirm (sometimes Post Owner may tag incorrectly), are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core (including .NET 5 and so on)? If you are using ASP.NET Core, have you tried HttpContext.Request.Form.Files? What is the alternative of Httpcontext.Current.Request.Files in Asp.Net Core 2.0?

As it's missing boundary directive, try excluding 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' header, it should be handled automatically:
this.http.post('/api/fileUpload', formData).subscribe(

More about content type header and AJAX: Pass Data to Service in Axios
