# How to do FileUpload in ASP.NET Core 6 and return file Url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, temporary-asp.net-files

I am going to save image local file and return image url:

```
namespace img_cleaner.Controllers;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async ValueTask<IActionResult> ImageReiceve(ImageUpload imageUpload)
    {
        MultipartFormDataContent form=new MultipartFormDataContent();
        HttpClient client=new HttpClient();
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(imageUpload.file);

        var fileStream = imageUpload.file?.OpenReadStream();

        StreamContent content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "file",
            FileName = imageUpload.file?.FileName
        };

        form.Add(content);

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/",form);
        var imgResult = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        var imgResultBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgResult);         

        return View(new ImageResult(){ ImageStringbase64 = imgResultBase64 });
    }
};
```

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Looks like you are posting the image contents to an external site (`localhost:5000`) and if the site supports serving images from assigned urls, you are fine. However, if not (it doesn't look like it does), consult whomever created this external site for details. If its yours, just make that exetnal site return the assigned url, together with the byte array.

Comment: Hi @Shoxrux, what's your problem here? How is your called api like? Pls share enough code.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319043/how-can-i-send-a-file-over-a-rest-api/73540622#73540622