# WCF Service application: The operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, web-services, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF Rest Webservice with stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366489/wcf-rest-webservice-with-stream)

I'm developing a WCF .NET Framework 4.0 with C#.

I've created this WCF with this Visual Studio Template:

[image]

I need to send an image with two or three parameters. This is all `OperationContract` that I have (I'm asking for the last one):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "orders/")]
    OrderContract[] allOrders();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "filteredOrders/")]
    OrderContract[] GetOrders(IdsMessage msg);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "completeFilteredOrders/")]
    OrderContract[] LoadCompleteFilteredOrders(IdsMessage msg);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "saveEReports/")]
    Boolean SaveEReports(EReportContract[] eReports);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "saveEReport/")]
    long SaveEReport(EReportContract eReport);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "UploadPhoto/{eReportId}/{imageType}")]
    Boolean UploadPhoto(string eReportId, string imageType, Stream fileContents);
}
```

And this is `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="EReportService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="EReportService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" maxBufferSize="2097152" transferMode="Streamed"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I run service I get the following exception:

> The operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream

If I do this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "UploadPhoto")]
Boolean UploadPhoto(Stream fileContents);
```

It works perfectly but I need to send more data with image.

This service is exposed for an **Android** tablet application. The following code show how I'm sending now images to server:

```
public static Boolean sendImage(String url, String filePath)
{
    try
    {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData;

        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(filePath);

        // populate the data to post
        formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        formData.add(OrderSpringController.FILE, resource);

        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(new MediaType("application","json")));

        // Sending multipart/form-data
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        // Populate the MultiValueMap being serialized and headers in an HttpEntity object to use for the request
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = 
                new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(formData, requestHeaders);

        GsonHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(messageConverter);

        // Create a new RestTemplate instance
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(messageConverter);

        // Make the network request, posting the message, expecting a String in response from the server
        ResponseEntity<Boolean> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                Boolean.class);

        // Return the response body to display to the user
        return response.getBody();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The error occurs when browsing to metadata endpoint (http://localhost:2351/RestServiceImpl.svc).

**How can I send an image and parameters?**

Comment: Disable streaming? Or serialize `eReportId` and `imageType` into your stream.

Comment: How can I serialize `ereportId` and `imageType` into my stream?

Comment: The error occurs when browsing to metadata endpoint (http://localhost:2351/RestServiceImpl.svc).

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366489/wcf-rest-webservice-with-stream

Answer (score 5):

If you switch to (BasicHttp or WSHttp )Binding then you can achieve your goal by composing a single data type including all your custom parameters via properties and the Stream object itself. Then you are making use of *messaging style* instead of RPC conversation. And pls pay attention to [MessageContract] family of WCF DTO decorators.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{
    [OperationContract]
    RemoteFileInfo DownloadFile(DownloadRequest request);

    [OperationContract]
    void UploadFile(RemoteFileInfo request); 
}
[MessageContract]
public class DownloadRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string FileName;
}

[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

[MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
public long Length;

[MessageBodyMember]
public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

public void Dispose()
{ 
    if (FileByteStream != null)
    {
        FileByteStream.Close();
        FileByteStream = null;
    }
}
```

}

This has necessary code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP

But I strongly suggest [WCF: using streaming with Message Contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339857/wcf-using-streaming-with-message-contracts) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/25/wcf-streaming-inside-data-contracts.aspx

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) is a  MUST, as well :)

Comment: I get this error: `Operation 'UploadPhoto' contract 'IRestServiceImpl' uses a MessageContract that has SOAP headers. MessageVersion not handle SOAP headers.` I have changed this: `Boolean UploadPhoto(PhotoUploadMessage photoMessage);`.

Comment: Seems like you didn't switch to BasicHttpBinding and still programming against REST (WebHttpBinding). If you change your configuration and refactor the service a bit this should work.
Speaking generally, REST is not the best way of streaming over internet. Why don't you switch to RPC (SOAP, BasicHttp)?

Comment: Pls CHeck out [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Upload-files-using-a-REST-13f16af2) and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668246/wcf-rest-file-upload.
But anyway you will have to create the container contract object. I recommend switching to BasicHttpBinding for streaming purpose.

Comment: Be also careful with your UriTemplate if you choose to stay with REST. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664712/restful-wcf-service-image-upload-problem) is a solution that worked.

Comment: I have more `[OperationContract]` on Web Service and they are RESTfull so, may I need to create a new `IRestServiceImpl.svc` to use `BasicHttpBinding`?

Comment: Pls update your question body with the list of all the operation contracts within that RESTful service, I need to look at the service factoring to answer this question correctly. Then I'll reply you with the steps you need to go through :). And also don't forget to mention what clients are you exposing the service for? (asp.net, php, java, mobile/desktop etc.)

Comment: I've updated my question with more details and code. If you need something else, please tell me. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I think I can send another data as part as `formData`like this: `formData.add("eReportId", eReportId);`. What do you think?

Comment: Hey :) I was able to done exactly what you need and it works. I'll be posting some key concepts today a bit later, and will send you the zipped project to your email from your website.

Comment: The error occurs when browsing to metadata endpoint (http://localhost:2351/RestServiceImpl.svc).

Comment: I believe `Order = 1` is redundant as you only have one body element

Comment: @OhadSchneider you're right, I removed the Order property.

Answer (score 1):

Try reordering your parameters so that the Stream ist the last one.

Also have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. I'm getting the same error: `The operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream`.

Comment: have a look at the accepted reply [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1728953.aspx/1). This seems to be a working sample of what you want to do.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: The error occurs when browsing to metadata endpoint (http://localhost:2351/RestServiceImpl.svc).

Answer (score 1):

I have created new type and selalize it

it contains the 3 values ( stream , reportid ,reporttype )

below is the code

```
namespace WcfService5
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {    
        [OperationContract]
        Boolean UploadPhoto(data fileContents);
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct data 
    {
        System.IO.Stream mystream;
        string ereport;
        string reporttype;
    }
}
```

here is the service code

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public bool UploadPhoto( data value)
    {
        return false;
    }     
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: The error occurs when browsing to metadata endpoint (http://localhost:2351/RestServiceImpl.svc).